# Longest Path through a given Node in an undirected and unweighted graph

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

I have a directed, unweighted graph G that may contain loops. My goal is to find the longest path that passes through a given node 'u' in the graph. The path might start from another node, but must include 'u'. It is important to note that the path should not revisit any nodes, and each node can be visited only once.

Note: This longest path not have to be the graph’s diameter.

Does anybody know of an algorithm that would solve this? And if yes, what would be its complexity?

Comment: Are you asking for an algorithm?

Comment: Yes. I am asking for an algorithm. Thanks

Comment: Look at each of the nodes that have edges that connect directly to $u$. Recursively look at the longest paths that go to those.

Comment: The longest path problem is NP-hard (even if you fix a vertex), we actually dont know better than an exponential algorithm for it.

Comment: Im looking for something more efficient. The solution probably use DFS with some changes in the input. I.e reverse the direction of some of edges, or maybe related some of the edge types in the DFS algorithm as discover edges.

Comment: Try reducing from Hamilton path